# Is there any way of getting an array name in hash in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

I'm using several arrays of identical structure in a Perl program, and at some point, I need to output there names. I.e., I need to get `'array_name'` from `@array_name`.
How can I do it? If it's impossible, can you suggest any convenient way of "relative" storing of arrays and their names?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is certainly possible, but I'd recommend to store your arrays as anonymous array references in a hash:

```
my %arrays = (
    'array_name' => [ qw(contents of array array_name) ],
    # etc
)
```

Then, to retrieve an array with name `$some_array_name`:

```
my @array = @{$arrays{"$some_array_name"}};
```

Comment: I think you meant `array_name` as the key and not `$array_name` in your retrieval example

Comment: No, I did mean "$array_name" -- actually I forgot to add "for an array by name `$array_name`" in the text

Comment: Placing the `$some_array_name` scalar in double quotes within the hash subscript is redundant.  Also it is important to note that `@array` will contain a shallow copy of the source array.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a hash of anonymous arrays as follows:

```
%HoA = (
    flintstones    => [ "fred", "barney" ],
    jetsons        => [ "george", "jane", "elroy" ],
    simpsons       => [ "homer", "marge", "bart" ],
);
```

You can set the first element of a particular array as follows:

```
$HoA{flintstones}[0] = "Fred";
```

To capitalize the second Simpson, apply a substitution to the appropriate array element:

```
$HoA{simpsons}[1] =~ s/(\w)/\u$1/;
```

You can print all of the families by looping through the keys of the hash:

```
for $family ( keys %HoA ) {
    print "$family: @{ $HoA{$family} }\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic name storage. It is just a name of the variable you use. If you need to store it, I'd recommend using an Hash like this:

```
$array->{name} = "array_name";
$array->{data} = [@array_name];
```

Comment: Please, if you down-vote, leave a comment. Noone will know what you think is wrong. (Incl. me.)